# In iPhoto, how can I disable the keyboard play button?

Tags: mac, itunes, macbook, iphoto

I use iPhoto '09 on my Mac.

Every time I hit my laptop's play button while in iPhoto, instead of iTunes playing my audio, iPhoto goes into a photo loop.

How can I get iPhoto to ignore the play button completely?

And a related question: Once iPhoto start playing a slideshow, how can I get it to stop?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to question #1 (deactivating <kbd>F7</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd> in iPhoto):

- go to Fahran Ahmad site: http://www.thebitguru.com/projects/iTunesPatch and download http://www.thebitguru.com/site_media/uploads/downloads/PlayButtoniTunesPatch-0.8.3.zip;
- open the folder "PlayButtoniTunesPatch";
- open the file "edit_rcd_bin.py";
- replace "*string_to_find = 'tell application id "com.apple.iTunes*" to launch'" with "*string_to_find = 'iPhoto'*".
- launch "Patch.command".

Easy and efficient (and undoable)!

Answer (score 0):

well i have one for question #2 - hit escape to stop the slideshow

maybe there is something in system prefs for removing the function

or in iphoto's prefs

Comment: Hitting esc should kill it, but for some reason it doesn't do anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. `Esc` works in iPhoto '11, but I don't have an older version running right now to test out. Perhaps hitting the button again (this time to pause) before hitting `Esc` would cause it to exit properly? Or perhaps <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

You can disable that key entirely by switching the top row to function keys (requiring the use of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key on your keyboard to get the alternate use). Do this by going into System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard, and check "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys."